# how to change one cell in a ruby 2d array?

Tags: ruby

Can someone explain this?

```
def digit_block(size = 1)
  col = 2 + 1*size
  row = 1 + 2*size
  r = []
  for i in 0...col
    r.push ' '
  end
  a = []
  for i in 0...row
    a.push r
  end
  a
end

block = digit_block
puts block.inspect
block[1][2] = 'x'
puts block.inspect
```

outputs:

```
[[" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " "]]
[[" ", " ", "x"], [" ", " ", "x"], [" ", " ", "x"]]
```

My understanding is block[1][2] only changes the cell at row 1 column 2, but why it changes all the cell in column 2?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  for i in 0...row
    # you are pushing the same array object to an array
    a.push r
  end
```

So every element in `block` is the same object.

```
block[0] === block[1]  # true
block[1] === block[2]  # true
```

***Update:***

You need to make a new array for every element, your code could be rewrote as below:

```
def digit_block(size = 1)
  Array.new(1 + 2*size){Array.new(2 + size){' '}}
end
```

Comment: so, how can we value to a particular cell?

Comment: @surase.prasad Just try my version of the function :)

Answer (score 0):

You are only generating a single array `r`. Even if you use that in multiple places, their identity is the same. If you change it in one location, it affects the same object in other locations. To answer the question in the title, you need to make a different array for each row.

```
def digit_block(size = 1)
  col = 2 + 1*size
  row = 1 + 2*size
  a = []
  for i in 0...row
    # For every iteration of the loop, the code here is evaluated,
    #  which means that the r is newly created for each row.
    r = []
    for i in 0...col
      r.push ' '
    end
    a.push r
  end
  a
end
```